# SP 2010 -- Row Level / List Item Security -- Parent / Child Relationship

Tags: 2010, permissions, designer-workflow

I have 2 Custom Lists in SharePoint 2010.

1. **Reconciliations**
2. **Reconciling Items**

I need to apply row level security on **Reconciling Items**,
based on the *Status* of the **Reconciliations** list item.

*Status* is a Choice field on **Reconciliations**...

And **Reconciling Items** has a lookup field for **Reconciliations**

I have successfully applied row level security to **Reconciliations** based on the *Status*.

> Is it possible to apply the same permissions on the related item(s) in **Reconciling Items** when the *Status* in **Reconciliations** changes?

What I've tried...

**A.**
I set up the same row level security on **Reconciling Items**, using the lookup to find the *Status* on **Reconciliations**. But this doesn't work because it only runs when **Reconciling Items** created / changes, not when *Status* changes on **Reconciliations**.

**B.**
Then I tried the other direction, adding to the workflow for **Reconciliations**. But when looking up **Reconciling Items** from **Reconciliations**, only the first item found would be affected, not all the items.

**C.**
Then I thought about adding an additional lookup field, *Status*, on **Reconciling Items**. But Choice fields cannot be included from a lookup. Not sure this would work anyway, if I were to change the field to a Single line of text. Don't think it would actually register a change...

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by using a folder content type as Reconciliations then put the Reconsiliation items into that folder.

Items in folders automatically inherit their parents' permissions so this has the added benefit of not having too many item level permissions going on.

**Steps for Reconciliations folder content type in Reconciliations**

1. Create your Reconciliations content type based on the default folder content type. Use these [example steps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9bde807c-d00b-4750-945f-87dc45661231/adding-additional-fields-when-creating-a-new-folder-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) or do this through SharePoint Designer.
2. Add your Reconciliations content type to the Reconciliation Items list. (first allow management of content types through settings->advanced settings)
3. Apply your permissions logic to the Reconciliation folders, permissions will be inherited by the contained items.

This only leaves you with the problem of showing an "add" button that points to the items content type when you are inside a Reconciliation folder and to the folder content type when you are not in a folder.

Edit: this is similar to what [document sets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-c49c246d-31f1-4bfe-afe2-e26698b47e05) do for documents

Comment: makes sense, thank you -- the lists are used by a front-end web application, using web services to manage the data -- not really a problem as-is, but if someone were to stumble across the actual list -- can I shut off the view(s) on current 'items' list, until the changes are made to the application?

Comment: I guess you want to hide the list from the user entirely correct? You can do this in the list settings in SharePoint Designer. This article tells you the steps: http://aanuwizard.com/2010/05/how-to-hideunhide-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/